# PyPy and efficient arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pypy

My project currently uses NumPy, only for memory-efficient arrays (of bool_, uint8, uint16, uint32).

I'd like to get it running on PyPy which doesn't support NumPy. (failed to install it, at any rate)

So I'm wondering: Is there any other memory-efficient way to store arrays of numbers in Python? Anything that is supported by PyPy? Does PyPy have anything of it's own?

Note: array.array is not a viable solution, as it uses a lot more memory than NumPy in my testing.

Comment: PyPy comes with `numpypy` (which is a clone of numpy, but still misses features)

Comment: The other question that has to be asked is why are you looking at using pypy? Are there other, easier optimisations that you can do first? What is your current performance bottleneck?

Comment: Thank you JBernardo. numpypy seems to work fine for my needs. :)

Comment: As to why I want to use PyPy - I have a server application written in Python and I'd like it to perform well. I've used Psyco in the past and found that it boosted performance greatly. I could rewrite parts or the whole thing in C, but I'd rather not.

Comment: bytearray is fast and compact for 8-bit numbers.

Answer (score 3):

array.array *is* a memory efficient array. It packs bytes/words etc together, so there is only a few bytes of extra overhead for the entire array.

The one place where numpy can use less memory is when you have a sparse array (and are using one of the sparse array implementations)

If you are not using sparse arrays, you simply measured it wrong.

array.array also doesn't have a packed bool type, so you can implement that as wrapper around an `array.array('I')` or a `bytearray()` or even just use bit masks with a Python long

Comment: Depending on your needs, there is also `cffi`, where you can declare and use arrays of C types or arrays of small C structures.

Comment: To measure memory, I tried initializing a very large array with random data and looked at the RAM Python was using. I also used array.array previously in production and found when I converted to numpy that RAM use was reduced by 50-70%. The arrays may be sparse, they're probably roughly 75% empty at any given time, I'd estimate.